# No PHP validation criteria in Views

Tags: views

In order to specify a PHP validation criteria for a View - do I need some additional module? In previous installation of Drupal I had this position in select box. Now there is everyone of them apart from PHP code. Where did it go?

[image: Screenshot from Views UI]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the PHP Filter module (Core, optional) is enabled.

Comment: So simple, so effective. I had no idea this is done by outside module and tried to look it up in google. THANK YOU.

Comment: You're welcome. The ability to enter/run custom PHP from the UI, anywhere in a Drupal site, is (at least in theory) a risk for the security and stability of your site. All modules that allow raw PHP input, (should) depend on the PHP Filter module, so you can easily disable PHP input in your entire site.